# Make multiple images in grid canvas expand with window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to plot 2 images next to each other using Tkinter.
I want to use Grid since I will position 10 images in a grid-like position.

In pack I can do it this way, what is the equivalent of that in the grid?

```
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import ttk, Canvas, BOTH, YES
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Widget Examples")

# Frame 1
frame1 = Canvas(root)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
pilImage1 = Image.open("testImage.jpg")
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage1)
frame1.create_image(0, 0, image=image1, anchor="nw")


# Frame 2
frame2 = Canvas(root)
frame2.grid(row=0, column=1)
pilImage2 = Image.open("testImage.jpg")
image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage2)
frame2.create_image(0, 0, image=image2, anchor="nw")
# Keep unchanged
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to make canvases and then plot the image inside these canvas. And what is the dimension of the grid with 10 images? 2x5? or 5x2?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria thanks for the follow-up questions.
First, I want to use canvas, because in one particular image I want the user to click on the image and get the co-ordinate 
 off the click from the image.
Second, the canvas images will be in 2 by 5.

Comment: You can get the image coordinate of click even in a `Label` I suppose

Comment: oh! I did not know that. I thought I strictly needed to use Canvas to get the coordinates. Okay, then I guess I will stick to Label. Thanks for the tip. So I should switch Canvas above to Label then, and that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that uses `Label` to show image and get the click coordinates too. You can also use nested loops to create the grid and place `Label` with `grid` geometry manager:

```
from tkinter import * # Better to use import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

def click_cord(e):
    print(f'x coodinate of click: {e.x}')
    print(f'y coodinate of click: {e.y}')
    print()

img_path = ['path_to_img1','path_to_img2',...] # List with path of 10 images
tk_lst = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(x)) for x in img_path] # ImageTk instances

for i in range(2): # Number of rows
    for j in range(5): # Number of columns
        lbl = Label(root,image=tk_lst[5*i+j])
        lbl.grid(row=i,column=j)
        lbl.bind('<Button-1>',click_cord) # Bind left click to the label

root.mainloop()
```

If you are wondering what `tk_lst[5*i+j]` is, it is just a way to index the list, `tk_lst`, in a nested loop, where the index variables, `i` and `j`, cannot be deduced as normal 0,1,2,3,... unless an expression is applied on it. The expression can be generalized as: `column_count * current_row_iteration + current_column_iteration`

Comment: hey @delrius ! Thanks for the answer. Can I please ask you how to get the color from `click_cord`.
I tried the following, but not sure how to pass the image:

`def click_cord(e, output):
    print(f"coords {e.x, e.y}, colors - {output[e.y, e.x]}")`

Comment: @JosephAdam You mean the color at which the mouse is at ?

Comment: Yes please! When the mouse clicks it displays the color of that pixel

Comment: @JosephAdam Nothing I know that does it by default, please ask a new question

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I started a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875163/get-pixel-color-from-click-on-image-with-tkinter